# Counting and numbering range of text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I am after a clever combination of Excel formulas that will be able to produce what I have manually typed into the yellow highlighted boxes on the screenshot.

What I need to produce is essentially, for the range of months on the far right column, to count each instance of it and order each one starting with 1 and incrementing by 1 until it changes to the next month.

[Screeshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmKLY.png)

I'm wondering if someone has in their brain a nice combination of nested formulas or something similar ready to go they could enlighten me with?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `column A` for the range of Months starting from row 1. In `B1` put `1`

In `B2` put `=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2)+1` and drag down.

Comment: Works well, thank you very much :)